# Merging input Streams with nodejs/ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm creating a very basic and rudimentary Video-Web-Chat. On the client side, I'm going to use a simple `getUserMedia` API call to capture the webcam data and send video-data as `data-blob` to my server.

From There, I'm planning to either use the `fluent-ffmpeg` library or just spawn `ffmpeg` myself and pipe that raw data to `ffmpeg`, which in turn, does some magic and pushes that out as `HLS` stream to an *Amazon AWS Service* (for instance), which then gets actually displayed on a Web Browser for all participating people in the video chat.

So far, I think all of this should be fairly easy to implement, but I keep my head spinning around the question, how I can create a "combined" or "merged" frame and stream, so the output HLS data from my server to the distributing cloud service has only to be one combined data stream to receive.

If there are 3 people in that video chat, my server receives 3 data streams from those clients and combines these data streams (from the individual web-cam data sources) into one output stream.

How could that be accomplished?
Can I "create" a new frame with `ffmpeg`, so to speak? I would be very thankful if anybody could give me a heads up here, maybe I'm thinking in a complete wrong direction.

Another question which arises to me is, if I really can just "dump" any data, which I'm receiving from a *binary blob* created from `getUserMedia` or `MultiStreamRecorder` to `ffmpeg` or if I have to specify somewhere and somehow the exact codecs being used etc.?

Comment: Sounds like you're after a video mixer. FFmpeg does have some filters which can do that , e.g. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos. Also you may want to consider using WebRTC to transport your media rather than using a `data-blob`, that's what it's for after all. You could then you a webrtc capabale server such as jitsi or janus to do your mixing or alternatively SFU.

Answer (score 0):

The huge drawback when using hls streaming in a video conferencing application is the latency. You can have latencies up to 10 seconds which isn't ideal for live chat.

What you are looking for is an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) (Selective Forwarding Unit) which can redirect the data live from the browser -> server -> other browser. Latency is very low there and no need to store anything.

There are several technologies you can use like janus-gateway, kurento media server or jitsi for example. Me personally I use [mediasoup](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) which gives a little more flexibility.

[HERE](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms) is a simple video-conferencing project using mediasoup that can get you started.

If in the end you still want to use HLS for streaming, as it could also be handy to view video from the past, you can still use mediasoup to send the video to the server and then to ffmpeg which converts it to hls directly.

Here is a [Recording project](https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo) with an implementation of recording with ffmpeg. In this code it's saving as webm, but with some parameter tweaking you can save it as HLS. (send me a message if you want an implementation of that)